# Aside from the obvious stuff, do the partial functions that solve the quadratic equation have any interesting properties?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quadratics, universal-algebra

Let us define partial functions

$$f_+,f_- : \mathbb{R} \leftarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$$

so as to return the zeros of the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ whenever they exist, such that if $a > 0$, then $f_+(a,b,c)$ is the larger of the two roots, and $f_-(a,b,c)$ is the smaller of the two.

In particular, we define:

$$f_+(a,b,c) = \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}, \qquad f_-(a,b,c) = \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

So $f_+(a,b,c)$ and $f_-(a,b,c)$ are proper iff $b^2 \geq 4ac$ and $a \neq 0$.

For example, $f_+(1,-1,-1)$ is the golden ratio.

> **Question.** Apart from the obvious stuff, like
>
> - $(2af_+(a,b,c)+b)^2 = b^2-4ac$
> - $(2af_-(a,b,c)+b)^2 = -(b^2-4ac)$
> - $a(f_+(a,b,c)+f_-(a,b,c))=-b$
>
> whenever both sides of the equation are proper, do $f_+$ and $f_-$ satisfy any other interesting identities and/or relationships to each other and/or to addition and multiplication? For example, can we say anything interesting about $f_+(a+a',b,c)$ or $f_+(aa',b,c)$ or $f_+(f_+(a,b,c),d,e)$, etc?
>
> Furthermore, does $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with these partial functions and possibly one or two others form an interesting partial algebraic structure in its own right, and live naturally in a well-behaved category of similar such structures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Viete's Formulas and some simple algebra, we see that $cx^2 + bx + a = 0$ has roots that are inverses of the roots of $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, so

$$\left\{f_-(c, b, a), f_+(c, b, a)\right\} = \left\{\frac{1}{f_-(a, b, c)}, \frac{1}{f_+(a, b, c)}\right\}$$

It should be possible to generate a large amount of such relations using similar processes (I'm sure textbooks pertaining to quadratic equations have many of such root-transforming problems).

---

Another example I've worked out:

By finding an equation whose roots are the squares of the roots of $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$,

$$\left\{f_{\{-,+\}}(a^2, 2ac - b^2, c^2)\right\} = \left\{\left(f_{\{-, +\}}(a, b, c)\right)^2\right\}$$